# Gsutil Terminal Command not actually updating files in the Cloud Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Linux Distro: Pop!_OS 19.10 Ubuntu

For context, I'm hosting a static website through Google Cloud Bucket. 
So I tried executing the command

```
gsutil -m cp -r ejsout gs://evaapp.xyz
```

to push to my storage bucket.

The command copies all the files successfully, returning

```
/ [333/333 files][ 19.7 MiB/ 19.7 MiB] 100% Done 998.4 KiB/s ETA 00:00:00 
Operation completed over 333 objects/19.7 MiB.
```

but when I go and look at the bucket online, the files aren't overwritten.

I've waited for hours or days and nothing happens to the files on Google Cloud Console. Only new files that haven't been created show up in the bucket console but not existing files. I have to manually update the files through cloud console for it to update.

Anyway to fix this? Feel free to close this issue because I'm bad at this and I couldn't find any helpful documentation on this. It's just annoying, I want to do the push from the terminal. Thanks!

Comment: How long did you wait after the copy before checking in the console? The console does not update instantly. There is a time lag that can be several minutes before updates are visible in the console.

Comment: @JohnHanley Hi John! Thanks for your response. I've done this and waited days, pretty much nothing has changed. New files that have not been created before pop up almost immediately on the bucket, while existing files with changed data show no update, even after hours.

Comment: Define what you mean by "when I go and look at the bucket online"? Do you mean inside the Google Cloud Console, or via some other method? I have been working with Google Cloud Storage for more than eight years. I have not seen your problem. Edit your question with details so that we can reproduce this.

Comment: @JohnHanley I've been viewing it directly inside the Google Cloud Console object browser, not through any other method.

Comment: @KylerChin do you have any [lifecycle management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/managing-lifecycles) or [object versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-object-versioning#check) enabled for the bucket? Please edit your question explaining exactly how your bucket is configured in order to try a reproduction of the issue.